# ActiveMQ Artemis crash re-connect

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

My ActiveMQ Artemis 2.32.0 in K8s pod keeps crashing for some reason.
After the crash and pod restart my existing clients get this exception:

```
org.apache.qpid.jms.exceptions.JmsConnectionFailedException: The JMS connection has failed: Transport connection remotely closed.`
org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.exceptions.ProviderFailedException: Transport connection remotely closed.
```

I am creating the connection using this code:

```java
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new JmsConnectionFactory(activeMqAmpq);
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
```

I do not see any methods to check if the connection is still active or alive. I have read about reconnecting automatically and apparently is not possible after a crash. Hence I would like to know if the connection is still active. If not, then I can re-connect before creating a session and sending a message.

Comment: Crash always on connect or in random intervals? Please be more specific.

Comment: I have seen it a random times, it could be due to the resource allocation in K8s, but I am not able to figure it out without the logs.

Comment: I have read about reconnecting automatically and apparently is not possible after a crash, hence I would like to know if the connection is still active, if not, then I can re-connect before creating a session and sending a message. Thx

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/determine-reason-pod-failure/

Comment: Why do you say that reconnecting automatically is not possible after a crash?

Comment: I am trying to find the documentation which mentioned that is not possible to auto-reconnect after a crash, but I know that it it does not auto-reconnect b/c I get: 
`ProviderFailedException` and `JmsConnectionFailedException`.
I maybe missing some connection settings, hence my question here. Thx

Comment: It's hard to say if there's a problem since you haven't provided details about your connection URL.

Comment: This is my connection:
`ConnectionFactory cf = new JmsConnectionFactory("amqp://localhost:5672?jms.username=artemis&jms.password=artemis");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JMS doesn't provide any methods to check whether the connection is active or not. You should simply *use* the connection and if any exceptions are thrown then you should deal with them accordingly (e.g. invoke `close()` on the existing `Connection` and use the `ConnectionFactory` to create another one).

If you happen to be using a [`MessageListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageListener.html) and are therefore waiting for a callback (i.e. not actively invoking JMS methods) then you should register an [`ExceptionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ExceptionListener.html) using [`Connection.setExceptionListener()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#setExceptionListener-javax.jms.ExceptionListener-).

Aside from this you might try using the [automatic reconnection features](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-2.5.0/docs/index.html#failover-configuration-options) available in the Qpid JMS client you're using. Even if you aren't using multiple instances of ActiveMQ Artemis you should still be able to use a URL with a single broker, e.g.:

```
failover:(amqp://host:5672)?failover.maxReconnectAttempts=20
```

Comment: Is this a reasonable way to check for active connection?

`private boolean isConnectionActive() {
 try {
   this.connection.getClientID();
   return true;
 } catch (Exception ignored) {
   return false;
 }
}`

Comment: No. Invoking `getClientID()` on the connection will only return the `String` that was set using `setClientID()`. It won't do anything to actually exercise network connectivity.